# Algorithm for cow to find the gap in a long fence

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

I am looking at this challenge:

> A shortsighted cow, named Sam, cannot find enough grass on its current pasture. It remembers that the pasture’s enclosing fence has a gap. Unfortunately, the fence is very long: for a full circle, it takes Sam  steps to walk along the fence. Sam can only see the gap if it is right next to it(remember the cow is shortsighted).
>
> In this question, you will design different algorithms that will enable Sam to find the gap that is  steps away from its current position. Sam is always located next to the fence. We call its start position origin. You may assume that  is much greater than . Design an algorithm that requires O() time efficiency to find a gap and show that its efficiency is indeed O(). You do not need to write the algorithm in pseudocode (you can if you want), but you have to describe the algorithm clearly.  is unknown. Sam can only walk along the fence.
>
> [image]

I cannot think of any ways to solve this problem because  is unknown and it seems that the time complexity always has something to do with  instead of .

Comment: If you know that the gap is defined to be `k` steps away from Sam's starting position, maybe you could just try walking `k` steps counterclockwise from Sam's starting position, then if the gap isn't there, returning to the starting point and walking `k` steps clockwise. Since one of these two points must be where the gap is, the total number of steps taken is upper-bounded by `3*k`, for a time complexity of `O(k)`.

Comment: @Telescope no, you don't know what _`k`_ is, just that it is much smaller than _`l`_, which you also do not know. e.g. going left and right by linearly increasing number of steps will be O(k^2) (left 1, right 1+2, left 2+3, right 3+4, ....).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go clockwise 1 step

Go counter-clockwise 2 steps

Go clockwise 4 steps...

Every time you change direction, you cover the same area you've already seen, plus that whole amount again, so on average *half* the time is spent examining a new part of the fence, on alternating sides.

You'll get to the gap in about 4k steps.

Comment: Hi, shouldnt that be O(2^k) instead of O(k)?

Comment: No!  Half of your time is spent exploring new fence, and half the time it will be on the correct side of the start position, so 25% of your time is spent exploring new fence in the direction of your goal.  If you start k steps away, it'll only take about 4k steps to get there.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find a solution where *N* is not involved, imagine that *N* is infinitely large, i.e. the fence is not circular, it is a straight line, extending infinitely in both directions.

Now we got that out of the way, it is clear that *any* successful algorithm will have to inspect both directions. So this means that after going in one direction for a while, but without success, one has to decide to go back to the starting point, and then go in the other direction. It is never a good choice to just keep going in one direction for ever, as it might well be that the gap is in the other direction, and thus the search will be unsuccessful.

So what remains is to decide when to go back to the starting point, and to look in the other direction.

A good choice would be to *double* each time the maximum distance you will go away from the origin in either of the two directions. If you fail to find the gap at either side, then double the maximum distance and repeat the process. It can also be another factor greater than 1 (like 3)... the principle is the same.

Let's name the two possible directions "left" and "right". So the cow would move as follows:

- Set distance to 1.
- first move that distance to the left
- then move twice that distance to the right, so you end up at the mirrored position at the right of the origin.
- then move that distance back to the left, so you end up at the origin.
- If at any time during this process we find the gap, we stop the algorithm
- Otherwise, double the distance, and repeat.

The total distance travelled after  iterations is:

| iteration | travelled in last iteration | travelled in total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 | 12 |
| 3 | 16 | 28 |
| 4 | 32 | 60 |
| .. | .. | .. |
|  | 2<sup>+1</sup> | Σ<sub><sub>i=1..</sub></sub>2<sup>+1</sup> = 2<sup>+2</sup> − 4 |

Each iteration of this loop we travel 4 times the currently set distance.

If the gap was at distance  from the origin, then we need 1+ceil(log<sub>2</sub>) iterations, where the last iteration would not be completed entirely, as it would be interrupted when the gap was found.

So the distance travelled will be less than 2<sup>+2</sup> − 4 with  = 1 + ceil(log<sub>2</sub>):

2<sup>ceil(log<sub>2</sub>)+3</sup> − 4

...which is less than or equal to:

8( + 1) − 4

And so the travelled distance is linear in